# How to detect a querystring like `?info`

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, query-string

I saw a web page that uses `page.aspx?info` or `page.aspx?download`. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
if (Request.QueryString["info"] != null)
{
    Label1.Text = "info";
}
```

Is there anyway to check if user entered `?info` after the url?

Comment: You may have to try something instead of Request.QueryString to see it. I don't remember the property, but there's one for getting the raw URL requested, you could check for info or download with that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify the name for a parameter it is taken as `null`.

Its value would be `info`

So you would have to check it as follows:

```
if(Request.QueryString[null]=="info")
{
    //Take some action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`?info` would result in empty value so your null check will fail. You want to iterate through Keys of QueryString collection to see if one is there.

Sample is available at MSDN -[HttpRequest.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx), you need to use `QueryString.AllKeys` with some sort of loop/LINQ query to check for presence of your key:

```
String[] arr1 = Request.QueryString.AllKeys; 
for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) 
{...
}
```